# Counter example that Lebesgue is translation invariant

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I seem to have a basic misunderstanding for what `translation invariant` means.

I thought it simply means that $\lambda(\varphi(x))=\lambda(\varphi(x+a))$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Here $\varphi$ is in $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$

---

But, this example doesn't work:

$\int_{[0,1]} x^2 d\lambda = \int_0^1 x^2 dx = \frac{1}{3} \neq \int_0^1 (x+1)^2 dx = \int_{[0,1]} (x+1)^2 d\lambda$

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by $\lambda(\varphi(x))=\lambda(\varphi(x+a))$.  What are $\varphi$ ad $x$?

Comment: Saying the measure is transltion-invariant means that $\int f(t+a)\,dt=\int f(t)\,dt$, **not** that $\int_0^1f(t+a)\,dt=\int_0^1f(t)\,dt$.

Comment: The parabola between $0$ and $1$ is not a translated version of the parabola between $1$ and $2$, so your example doesn't mean anything.

Comment: $I(\varphi(x+a))=I(\varphi(x))$ where $I$ is the integral on the whole line *is* equivalent to the translation invariance of the measure (although you need a bunch of machinery about approximation by continuous functions to restrict attention to $\varphi \in C_c$ here). But your example doesn't use the integral on the whole line so you aren't integrating a translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it:

$\varphi(x) = \{x^2$ if $x\in [0,1], \,\,0 $ else

Then: $\int \varphi(x) dx = \frac{1}{3} = \int \varphi(x+1) dx = \int_{-1}^{0} (x+1)^2 dx = \frac{1}{3}$